# I7m developing a website using CakePHP 3.7. I'm working on localhost and would like to send an email from localhost to gmail, but getting error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I am able to send an email from xampp (Mecury) localhost to localhost. But when I try to send an email from Gmail to the localhost I am not being able to do that.

Our main purpose is to send email from Gmail account to the localhost. How can I do that, Any help can be appreciated.

This is the code in my **app.php** file:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            //'className' => MailTransport::class,
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            /*
             * The following keys are used in SMTP transports:
             */
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],

    
'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => ['demotest@localhost.com' => 'demotest'],
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
         //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I am able to send an email from xampp (Mecury) localhost to localhost. But when I try to send an email from localhost to Gmail I am not being able to do that. Our main purpose is to send email from localhost to Gmail account. How can I do that, Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message, and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`)!

Comment: This is the error that i am getting while trying to send an email from Gmail to localhostError: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] 接続済みの呼び出し先が一定の時間を過ぎても正しく応答しなかったため、接続できませんでした。または接続済みのホストが応答しなかったため、確立された接続は失敗しました。

Comment: If you're getting SMTP connection timeout or Connection Refused then you might want to enable insecure access in google account.